# XSLT 2.0: XPath condition not working as expected for node selection

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I need to conditionally select certain nodes from an XML. I am comparing each node with a date. I want to select a node from a parent only if the the date I am using falls between `start_date` and `end_date` of this node. Given below is the XML:

```
    <queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
    <CompoundEmployee>
        <id>378</id>
        <person>
            <action>NO CHANGE</action>
            <person_id_external>10005557</person_id_external>
            <place_of_birth>Kromì?íž</place_of_birth>
            <personal_information>
                <action>PI01</action>
                <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                <start_date>2019-03-27</start_date>
                <workflow_request_id>1222</workflow_request_id>
            </personal_information>
            <personal_information>
                <action>PI02</action>
                <end_date>2019-03-26</end_date>
                <start_date>2012-02-01</start_date>
                <suffix>II</suffix>
            </personal_information>
            <employment_information>
                <action>EI01</action>
                <start_date>2012-02-01</start_date>
                <user_id>10005557</user_id>
                <job_information>
                    <action>JI01</action>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                    <start_date>2021-06-30</start_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
            <employment_information>
                <action>EI02</action>
                <end_date>2020-12-31</end_date>
                <start_date>2019-03-01</start_date>
                <user_id>10019560</user_id>
                <job_information>
                    <action>JI02</action>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                    <start_date>2021-01-01</start_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </person>
        <execution_timestamp>2021-09-15T09:12:37.000Z</execution_timestamp>
        <version_id>2105P0</version_id>
        <Start_Dates>
            <StartDate>2012-02-01</StartDate>
            <StartDate>2012-02-01</StartDate>
            <StartDate>2019-03-01</StartDate>
            <StartDate>2019-03-27</StartDate>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01</StartDate>
            <StartDate>2021-06-30</StartDate>
        </Start_Dates>
        <End_Dates>
            <EndDate>2019-03-26</EndDate>
            <EndDate>NA</EndDate>
            <EndDate>2020-12-31</EndDate>
            <EndDate>9999-12-31</EndDate>
            <EndDate>9999-12-31</EndDate>
            <EndDate>9999-12-31</EndDate>
        </End_Dates>
    </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

I am using below XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/queryCompoundEmployeeResponse">
    <queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
        <xsl:for-each select="CompoundEmployee">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:variable name="person" select="person" />
                <xsl:variable name="lastDate" select=".//EndDate[last()]"/>
                <xsl:variable name="start-dates" select="distinct-values(Start_Dates/StartDate)"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$start-dates">
                    <Person>
                        <StartDate>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>   
                        </StartDate>
                        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>   
                        <EndDate>                       
                            <xsl:value-of select="if ($i != last()) then xs:date($start-dates[$i+ 1]) - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') else $lastDate"/>
                        </EndDate>
                        <xsl:variable name="cDate" select="current()"/>
                       <!--<xsl:copy-of select="$person/* except $person/(personal_information | employment_information)"/>
                       <xsl:copy-of select="$person/personal_information[start_date le current() and current() le end_date]"/>
                       <xsl:copy-of select="$person/employment_information/job_information[start_date le current() and current() le end_date]"/>
                       -->                     
                       <!--<xsl:copy-of select="$person/employment_information[(replace(start_date,'-','') &lt;= replace($cDate,'-','')) and (replace(($cDate,'-','') &lt;= replace(end_date,'-','')) or not(end_date))]"/>-->
                       <xsl:copy-of select="$person/employment_information[start_date le current() and ((current() le end_date) or not(end_Date))]"/>
                    </Person>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
   <CompoundEmployee>
      <Person>
         <StartDate>2012-02-01</StartDate>
         <EndDate>2019-02-28</EndDate>
         <employment_information>
                        <action>EI01</action>
                        <start_date>2012-02-01</start_date>
                        <user_id>10005557</user_id>
                        <job_information>
                              <action>JI01</action>
                              <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                              <start_date>2021-06-30</start_date>
                        </job_information>
                  </employment_information>
      </Person>
      <Person>
         <StartDate>2019-03-01</StartDate>
         <EndDate>2019-03-26</EndDate>
         <employment_information>
                        <action>EI01</action>
                        <start_date>2012-02-01</start_date>
                        <user_id>10005557</user_id>
                        <job_information>
                              <action>JI01</action>
                              <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                              <start_date>2021-06-30</start_date>
                        </job_information>
                  </employment_information>
         <employment_information>
                        <action>EI02</action>
                        <end_date>2020-12-31</end_date>
                        <start_date>2019-03-01</start_date>
                        <user_id>10019560</user_id>
                        <job_information>
                              <action>JI02</action>
                              <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                              <start_date>2021-01-01</start_date>
                        </job_information>
                  </employment_information>
      </Person>
      <Person>
         <StartDate>2019-03-27</StartDate>
         <EndDate>2020-12-31</EndDate>
         <employment_information>
                        <action>EI01</action>
                        <start_date>2012-02-01</start_date>
                        <user_id>10005557</user_id>
                        <job_information>
                              <action>JI01</action>
                              <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                              <start_date>2021-06-30</start_date>
                        </job_information>
                  </employment_information>
         <employment_information>
                        <action>EI02</action>
                        <end_date>2020-12-31</end_date>
                        <start_date>2019-03-01</start_date>
                        <user_id>10019560</user_id>
                        <job_information>
                              <action>JI02</action>
                              <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                              <start_date>2021-01-01</start_date>
                        </job_information>
                  </employment_information>
      </Person>
      <Person>
         <StartDate>2021-01-01</StartDate>
         <EndDate>2021-06-29</EndDate>
         <employment_information>
                        <action>EI01</action>
                        <start_date>2012-02-01</start_date>
                        <user_id>10005557</user_id>
                        <job_information>
                              <action>JI01</action>
                              <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                              <start_date>2021-06-30</start_date>
                        </job_information>
                  </employment_information>
         <employment_information>
                        <action>EI02</action>
                        <end_date>2020-12-31</end_date>
                        <start_date>2019-03-01</start_date>
                        <user_id>10019560</user_id>
                        <job_information>
                              <action>JI02</action>
                              <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                              <start_date>2021-01-01</start_date>
                        </job_information>
                  </employment_information>
      </Person>
      <Person>
         <StartDate>2021-06-30</StartDate>
         <EndDate>9999-12-31</EndDate>
         <employment_information>
                        <action>EI01</action>
                        <start_date>2012-02-01</start_date>
                        <user_id>10005557</user_id>
                        <job_information>
                              <action>JI01</action>
                              <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                              <start_date>2021-06-30</start_date>
                        </job_information>
                  </employment_information>
         <employment_information>
                        <action>EI02</action>
                        <end_date>2020-12-31</end_date>
                        <start_date>2019-03-01</start_date>
                        <user_id>10019560</user_id>
                        <job_information>
                              <action>JI02</action>
                              <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                              <start_date>2021-01-01</start_date>
                        </job_information>
                  </employment_information>
      </Person>
   </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

Required Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
    <CompoundEmployee>
        <Person>
            <StartDate>2012-02-01</StartDate>
            <EndDate>2019-02-28</EndDate>
            <employment_information>
                <action>EI01</action>
                <start_date>2012-02-01</start_date>
                <user_id>10005557</user_id>
                <job_information>
                    <action>JI01</action>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                    <start_date>2021-06-30</start_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <StartDate>2019-03-01</StartDate>
            <EndDate>2019-03-26</EndDate>
            <employment_information>
                <action>EI01</action>
                <start_date>2012-02-01</start_date>
                <user_id>10005557</user_id>
                <job_information>
                    <action>JI01</action>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                    <start_date>2021-06-30</start_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
            <employment_information>
                <action>EI02</action>
                <end_date>2020-12-31</end_date>
                <start_date>2019-03-01</start_date>
                <user_id>10019560</user_id>
                <job_information>
                    <action>JI02</action>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                    <start_date>2021-01-01</start_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <StartDate>2019-03-27</StartDate>
            <EndDate>2020-12-31</EndDate>
            <employment_information>
                <action>EI01</action>
                <start_date>2012-02-01</start_date>
                <user_id>10005557</user_id>
                <job_information>
                    <action>JI01</action>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                    <start_date>2021-06-30</start_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
            <employment_information>
                <action>EI02</action>
                <end_date>2020-12-31</end_date>
                <start_date>2019-03-01</start_date>
                <user_id>10019560</user_id>
                <job_information>
                    <action>JI02</action>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                    <start_date>2021-01-01</start_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01</StartDate>
            <EndDate>2021-06-29</EndDate>
            <employment_information>
                <action>EI01</action>
                <start_date>2012-02-01</start_date>
                <user_id>10005557</user_id>
                <job_information>
                    <action>JI01</action>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                    <start_date>2021-06-30</start_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <StartDate>2021-06-30</StartDate>
            <EndDate>9999-12-31</EndDate>
            <employment_information>
                <action>EI01</action>
                <start_date>2012-02-01</start_date>
                <user_id>10005557</user_id>
                <job_information>
                    <action>JI01</action>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                    <start_date>2021-06-30</start_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </Person>
    </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

I am getting `employment_information(action=EI02)` in last two Person records even when the dates do not match, which should not be the case. For some reasons, condition:

```
$person/employment_information[start_date le current()
                and ((current() le end_date) or not(end_Date))]
```

does not seems to work correctly.
I need to do this for other nodes as well.

Comment: Is the capital "D" in `end_Date` a small mistake here, or is that in your original code?

Comment: Aah, silly mistake! Thanks for pointing out. Changing it to end_date worked.